# Probability conditioning- which interpretation is correct?

Tags: probability

I am very confused about the following:

Let us define $VaR_u(Y)$ as $\inf \{l:F_Y(l)\geq\ u \}$ where $F_Y$ is the CDF of the random variable Y.

Suppose $A $ and $X$ are random variables and suppose we have $VaR_u(AX)=5$. Furthermore, suppose we are interested in the following probability $P(AX>VaR_u(AX)|A=a)$. It seems as if there are two ways to deal with this probability, but surely there must be only one.

First we can take the stance that $VaR_u(AX)$ is a fixed quantity, namely 5. Thus we have $$P(AX>VaR_u(AX)|A=a)=P(AX>5|A=a)=P(aX>5)=P(aX>VaR_u(AX))$$

On the other hand one could argue that $VaR_u(AX)$ is dependent on the value of $A=a$ such that we have $$P(AX>VaR_u(AX)|A=a)=P(aX>VaR_u(aX))=1-u$$

I am inclined to believe that the first interpretation is the right one, but how does one 'choose'?

**Edit: Assume A and X to be independent.**

Answer (score 1):

$\text{VaR}_u(AX)$ clearly becomes a different quantity when you condition on $A$. Consider:

$$
\text{VaR}_u(AX) = \inf\lbrace l: \mathbb P(AX \leq l) \geq u \rbrace
$$
whereas
$$
\text{VaR}_u(AX \mid A=a) = \inf\lbrace l: \mathbb P(AX \leq l \mid A = a) \geq u \rbrace
$$
You can look $\mathbb P(AX \leq l)$ as:
$$
\mathbb P(AX \leq l) = \int\mathbb P(AX \leq l \mid A = a)f_A(a)da
$$
where $f_A$ is the marginal density of $A$. You clearly wouldn't assume in general that
$$
P(AX \leq l \mid A = a) = \int\mathbb P(AX \leq l \mid A = a)f_A(a)da
$$
Since, as you can see from the integral, you need the joint density of $A$ and $X$ to calculate $P(AX \leq l \mid A = a)$, I believe you cannot calculate $\mathbb P(AX > \text{VaR}_u(AX) \mid A = a)$ by only knowing $\text{VaR}_u(AX) = 5$. Conclusively, this would mean that both of the approaches you suggested are wrong.

Edit:
In case of independence, the second one holds because
$$
\text{VaR}_u(AX \mid A = a) = 
\inf \lbrace l : \mathbb P(AX  \leq l \mid A = a) \geq u \rbrace = 
\inf \lbrace l : \mathbb P(aX  \leq l) \geq u \rbrace = \text{VaR}_u(aX)
$$

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question because this is not what I meant, I am not interested in actually calculating the conditional probability: I am only interested in whether the conditioning affects the VaR. I can see that $VaR_u(aX)$ is different from $VaR_u(AX)$, but my question is does it hold that $$P(AX>VaR_u(AX)|A=a)=P(aX>VaR_u(AX))$$  or does it hold that $$P(AX>VaR_u(AX)|A=a)=P(aX>VaR_u(aX))$$

Comment: @Joogs Well, my point was that neither of those hold. $\text{VaR}_u(AX)$ uses the distribution of the product variable $AX$. When you condition on $A$ you get a different distribution, so that you need $\text{VaR}_u(AX \mid A = a)$. That is different from both $\text{VaR}_u(AX)$ and $\text{VaR}_u(aX)$. You gotta remember that $\text{VaR}_u(AX)$ is a function of the joint distribution of $A$ and $X$, you cannot just swap $A$ for a constant.

Comment: @Joogs and by the way, even if you treat $\text{VaR}_u(AX)$ as a constant, neither of the identities hold, because you don't have $P(AX < x \mid A = a) = P(aX < x)$ unless $A$ and $X$ are independent.

Comment: You're right, thank you for that. If A and X were independent though, then the first identity holds but not the second?  Because I am interested in knowing whether $ VaR_u(AX)$ should be treated as a constant, such that it does not change if the probability is taken to be conditional on a particular value $A=a$.

Comment: @Joogs see edit

Comment: So could you point out the mistake in the first identity then?  I agree with the edit in your anwser but I dont think it translates into the second identity I wrote down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59025/discussion-between-joogs-and-slug-pue).